# Method overloading in different classes

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading

Is it possible to have perform method overloading in different classes.

```
class Parent{
    // Private method
    private void method1(){
        System.out.println("In private method of Parent class");
    }
    void method2(){
    }
    void method3(){
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    void method3(int i){
    }
}
```

To perform overloading it is necessary to have two methods of same name and with different signature in the class. but in inheritance how does it work.
In inheritance is it true that copy of non private method is created in the child class? 
In this example overloading is performed or not?

Comment: No, for method overloading you must have the same method signature.

Comment: No, overloading happens within the same class. @drgPP you are talking about  overriding

Comment: @LaurentiuL. oh yes, you are right, i have confused the terms.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. But when we perform inheritence we inherit the non private methods of Parent class in our class so if i create a method with same name in my child class but with different argument then there will be two methods with same name present in my Child class. So overloading can be performed.

Answer (score 3):

[Overloading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9) means methods with same name but different signature but not override equivalent for *particular* `class`. It's subject of class and not related to it's parent *or* child. Moreover, if parent has overloaded methods than child may or may not have the same behavior. Moreover, if any `interface` contains the overloaded signatures your class ultimately have the overloaded methods.

Note here that you have not overloaded `method3(int i)` with `method()` of parent, even more method of `Child` is not related to method of it's parent in your case. You can only override `non-private` and `non-static` methods of parent but you can not overload them, there is no meaning of *overloading* them.

Answer (score 0):

**Overriding** - Redefining the methods **in the Sub Class** with out disturbing the signature. This is also called as Dynamic Binding, which will be decided during Runtime based upon the object being passed.

**Overloading** - Redefining the methods **with in the same Class** by changing the method signatures. This is also called as Static Binding, which will be decided during compile time.

Here, in your particular example, we SHOULD NOT say that the method3() is overloaded as we did not re-define method3() more than one time with in the same class.